# Deploy JHipster app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jhipster, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just created a sample JHipster application and generate a war file. 
I created a Elastic Beanstalk with Tomcat as environment and uplaoded the war file. 
The beanstalk goes to degraded status.

Here are the error logs. Also is there any recommended way to deploy JHipster apps to elastic beanstalk?

```
[Instance: i-0747156d94153abba] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...pamodelgen-5.2.17.Final.jar extracting: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib-provided/mapstruct-processor-1.2.0.Final.jar extracting: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib-provided/spring-boot-configuration-processor-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/02unzip.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

/var/log/eb-activity.log

```
extracting: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/guava-25.1-jre.jar  
creating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib-provided/
extracting: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib-provided/hibernate-jpamodelgen-5.2.17.Final.jar  
extracting: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib-provided/mapstruct-processor-1.2.0.Final.jar  
extracting: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib-provided/spring-boot-configuration-processor-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar   (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
[2018-11-07T04:14:06.917Z] INFO  [3168]  - [Application deployment jhipster@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/02unzip.sh] : Activity failed.
[2018-11-07T04:14:06.917Z] INFO  [3168]  - [Application deployment jhipster@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Activity failed.
[2018-11-07T04:14:06.917Z] INFO  [3168]  - [Application deployment jhipster@1/StartupStage0] : Activity failed.
[2018-11-07T04:14:06.919Z] INFO  [3168]  - [Application deployment jhipster@1] : Completed activity. Result:
Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup failed
```

Comment: had the same issue, have you solved it?

Comment: @HaifengZhang you may want to ask your own question. This one hasn't been touched in a year. That said, I would try to ask a better question. JHipster is an app generator that generates apps using other technology (Spring Boot, Angular), etc, and in fact those technologies are optional (you don't need to use Angular). If you are having trouble deploying, it's likely a problem with your configuration of the used technologies, not the app generator.